# Document Web Part - Show Full Height w/o Scrollbars?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a Document library webpart in Sharepoint online, modern Sharepoint site.  This library shows a view and [is set to autosize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsiNf.png).  There are 76 items (all pages) that are retrieved with this view.

Unfortunately, on the page where this Document library web part is embedded, it does not display in full height.  [Instead it gets a vertical scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb8uC.png) and is frustratingly short.

I would like to have it display the full height, all 76 items, without any frame vertical scroll.  Since the webpart's frame is also borderless, I could see how certain individuals could not understand they must position their cursor mid page to scroll downward to see all the content.  Having two scrollbars is a weird user experience and seems super unnecessary.

I've experimented with the view's Item List as well, with no luck.  [Item List settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9ncs.png)

Open to any and all suggestions, I haven't managed to find a solution - posts seems to suggest autosize should do what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no other way to adjust the height of a web part than the one you've tried by editing its size.